# Need Help. How to extract list from .txt and sort with input

Tags: python, list

Okay So, i have a dilemma. I have a document filled with names of countries. Now i need to get the list in python with open. Done that. However I am required to make a program that inputs a letter and gives all the countries that start with that letter. cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: In particular, "can't seem to figure it out" is not a problem specification.  Are you trying to tell us that you don't know how to see whether a string starts with a given letter?  You can't extract the country name from the document?

Comment: no no not at all. What i mean by cant figure it out, is sorting a list from an external document with a given letter by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getcountries(country_list, letter):
    output = []
    for x in country_list:
        if x[:1].lower() == letter.lower():
            output.append(x)
            print (x)
    return(output)
```

pass this function the list of country names, and the letter to search for.
it will print the name of each country, and will return a list of those countries.

Comment: Thanks ! Understood now, makes sense. I've changed it slightly to meet my exact needs.